# FFMPEG.exe that ignores parameters

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a program that needs to use ffmpeg.exe with fixed parameters, but the input file is already in the output format required.  I have no way of editing the parameters that the program is using and wondered if there is an alternative version of ffmpeg that would ignore all parameters except for the input and output and stream copy the video and audio?

The objective is to minimize my CPU consumption by passing the input to output rather than transcoding with the parameters set by my program.

Comment: A)You should include some examples pasted from the command line.   B)Sounds like you should use a shell script and that ignores 'parameters' or ignores whatever and calls ffmpeg how you want it.

Comment: How (and why) would ffmpeg know to ignore any parameter passed to it? It is expected that if a user doesn't want to set an optional parameter, they don't supply it.

Comment: @barlop - Thank you for this suggestion! This seems like a great path to my solution.  This almost works for me, but since I'm weak at programming I encountered a blurp with my input file having two equal signs that I couldn't address with a quick Google search.  I'm planning on building a custom "ffmpeg.exe" that grabs the input and output parameters and calls the real ffmpeg (renamed to "ffmpeg (2).exe") with stream copy settings.